# moving my Issue Tracking list from environment to another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, issue-tracking

I have added an issue tracking list on my SharePoint 2013 staging server. I did some test on it.

Now I need to move the list with its content type to our production server. So, what is the best approach to follow to move the list to production without having to re-build it again?

Second question: How I can reset all the counters inside the list in production, such as the issue number to be back to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways by which you can guarantee that the target server has the necessary lists and schemas but leveraging STP package is a good practice.

### Package the lists into STP packages

So let’s package `SharePoint Issue Tracking` list into a STP package.
You can do this via either server UI or SPD UI as shown below. 
[image]

Then, you will see the following screen where you can type in the name and choose to package the contents as well.
[image]

And if successful, it will guide you to a place where you can download the package.

[image]

Click the link and download the package for later use.

If successful, you must have STP package.

### Deploy the STP package

Open the target site in your browser and go to `Site Settings`. You can find ‘List templates’ menu under `Web Designer Galleries` group.

[image]

Using the ‘Upload Document’ under ‘Files’ menu, upload the STP package.

[image]

### Create list using the deployed list template

You can create the list from the deployed list template. Go to `Site Contents` in the navigation menu in the server and click ‘add an app’. You should be able to find `SharePoint Issue Tracking` icon.

[image]

Create `SharePoint Issue Tracking` lists using this menu.

### Prerequisites for list templates

Your list must meet the following criteria to move a list by using a list template ([source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/copying-or-moving-sharepoint-lists-HA001154562.aspx)):

1. The list must contain less than 10 megabytes (MB) of list data.
2. You must be a member of a site group with the Manage Lists right on the source site and on the destination site. By default, the Manage Lists right is included in the Web Designer and Administrator site groups.
3. The source site and the destination site must be based on the same site template.

### References

[Packaging SharePoint 2013 List, Site, and Reusable Workflow and How to Deploy the Package](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/30/packaging-list-site-and-reusable-workflow-and-how-to-deploy-the-package.aspx)

Comment: it worked as a magic ,, thanks but can i knwo what are the advantages and disadvantages of using this apprach comparing to backup / Restore the list ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. The answer has been updated with information about criteria for list templates (please follow section - Prerequisites for list templates)

Comment: in my current situation both sites are team sites. but you mean if i save a issue tracking list from a team iste, and then i uploaded it inside let say enterprise wiki , then it will not work ?

Comment: yep, if source and target sites are different (site templates), it will not work

Comment: HI vadim , can you look at a similar question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121525/uploaded-list-template-not-listed-under-add-an-app